# need help replacing extension of .jpg to .png or convert image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

The issue is that when this page loads... it pulls the .jpg image because that extension is hard coded (notice _image1.jpg) sometimes there might not be a .jpg image and there are .png images. I want to initially pull .jpg images but if that isn't available I want the .png images... How can I do this? I was wondering if there is a way to just rewrite the extension if the .jpg image isnt available.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    dealers = $.parseJSON(dealer_json);

    $('#productdealersTable .productdealers_dealerid').each(function(i, element) {
        var elemName = $(this).attr("name");
        var elemValue = $(this).val();
        var count = elemName.substring(23, elemName.length);
        elemName = elemName.replace('productdealers_dealerid','dealerid_display_value');
        $('#'+elemName).html($(this).find('option:selected').html());
        var name = $(this).find('option:selected').html();
        var cleanedname = name.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi,'');
        $(this).parent().removeClass().addClass('fieldinput '+cleanedname).addClass();
        var elemValue = $(this).val();
        jQuery('#dealerid_display_value'+count).html('<img src="/folder-Files/dealerLogos/'+elemValue+'_image1.jpg" />');

        var linkDiv = $(this).parent().find('.snapshotLink');
        var mpDiv = $(this).parents('.half').find('.marketplace_div');
        $.each(dealers.dealers, function(i, item) {
            if (dealers.dealers[i].id==elemValue) {
                dealers.dealers[i].show_in_pims == true ? linkDiv.show() : linkDiv.hide();
                dealers.dealers[i].sc == true ? mpDiv.show() : mpDiv.hide();
                if (dealers.dealers[i].scraped == 1) {
                    $('#dealers_scraped'+count).val(dealers.dealers[i].scraped);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    });



<div class="productdealersItemHeader">
                <h3><span class="h3pad"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="quickRetailersShowHide" id="quickRetailerOptionShowHide%count%" onclick="showQuickRetailerOptions(%count%);"><span class="dealerid_display_value" id="dealerid_display_value%count%"><img src="/Portal-Files/dealerLogos/%productdealers_dealerid_selectedValue%_image1.jpg"/></span></a></span></h3>
                <div class="dealerHandle productdealersActive"></div>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="deleteRetailerLink deleteRowButton productdealersActive" id="productdealersDeleteImg%count%" onclick="deleteListRow('productdealers', '%count%');">Delete</a>
</div>
```

Comment: store the correct filename/path in the data, otherwise you're fixing the wrong problem.

Comment: Please ask a [mcve]

Comment: @KevinB unfortunately I can't control which filename/path gets stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a simple request against that image - and if it is available use it, otherwise look for the png format.

```
var image = "http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/408/287.jpg";

function setImages(el, imagesrc) {
  $.get(imagesrc)
    .done(function() {
      document.getElementById(el).src = imagesrc;
    }).fail(function() {
      if (imagesrc.match(/\.jpg$/))
        setImages(el, imagesrc.replace(/\.jpg$/, ".png"))
    });
}


setImages("foo", image)
```

Comment: can you explain what the el parameter is? or how i can call my class name or Id? to be used in your example. not sure how to pass "dealerid_display_value" into that function

Comment: well, in this case it's "foo". not sure what el means tho. It appears as though it should contain an element id.